# How to find the basis of the null space of the stated Skew-symmetric Matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a real matrix $A \in \mathbb{M}_{3 \times 3}$ such that $A^T A = \beta I$ where $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^+$. $A$ has an eigenvalue of $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ with multiplicity $k = 3$ and a respective set of linearly independent eigenvectors $e_1, e_2, e_3 \in \mathbb{R}^3.$ Find a basis for the null space of matrix $B = \beta (A^T − A).$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Have you tried anything yet?