# Find a Basis for the Nullspace of a Skew-Symmetric Matrix with Given Properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I came across this past exam question:
Consider a real matrix $A_{3x3}$ such that $A^T A = βI$ where $β ∈ \mathbb{R}^+$. $A$ has an
eigenvalue of $λ_1 ∈ \mathbb{R}$ with multiplicity $k = 3$ and a respective set of linearly independent eigenvectors $e_1, e_2, e_3 ∈ \mathbb{R}^3$. Find a basis for the null space of matrix $B = β(A^T − A)$.

So my ideas about how to approach this so far has been as follows:

1. Using the fact that $A^T A = βI$, this implies that $A$ has linearly independent columns.
2. Since $det(A^T-\lambda I) = det((A-\lambda I)^T)=det(A-\lambda T)$, then the eigenvalue of A is the same as that of $A^T$.
3. $B = β(A^T − A)$ is skew-symmetric.
4. Now my feeling is that the basis of $null(B)$ should be written in terms of something to do with $e_1, e_2, e_3$.

What I don't know what to do is relate the eigenvectors of $A$ with the ideas above. Any help (preferably hints) is appreciated. (*Note: The superscript in $A^T$ means the transpose of $A$*

Comment: Can you infer $A= \pm \sqrt{\beta}\cdot I$ ?  This means $A$ is symmetric, so $A^T-A=\mathbf 0$

Comment: Is this a hint, or are you asking me if it's possible?

Comment: in either case the right thing to do is for you to see how it might be possible... this is a duplicate of an old (and unanswered) thread.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3752521/how-to-find-the-basis-of-the-null-space-of-the-stated-skew-symmetric-matrix